# Different errors when using .NET framework assembly in .NET standard via nuget vs manual reference

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, nuget, .net-standard

I created a ASP.NET Core web application. In this solution I also have a .NET Standard 2.0 project.

First I added a reference from .NET Standard project to a dll (.NET framework 4.6.1) manually without any issues and it works fine. I have then created a Nuget package for .NET framework dll, and tried to install this package in .NET Standard project.

I got an error

```
Package xxx was restored using .net framework, version = 4.6.1. instead of project target framework '.NET standard, version = v2.0'. This package may not be fully compatible with your project.
```

I am confused, how come i can use a .net framework assembly when referenced manually, and when it is installed via nuget i receive this error.

Further more, when i install this nuget in .NET Core 2.1. project (same solution) i get the same error.

Comment: A .NET Standard project should never use a reference of .NET Framework, https://blog.lextudio.com/which-class-library-project-to-go-in-visual-studio-2015-2017-a48710cf3dff If you made a mistake in the beginning, then any following issues are expected.

Comment: ad "should never use a reference of .NET Framework": I'd suggest testing the dll for possibly incompatible API usage using [ApiPort](https://github.com/Microsoft/dotnet-apiport). If this looks good the dll should be fine to use. But if this is a project you are developing, I suggest moving it to .NET Standard or multi-target to both Framework and Standard. But for third-party dlls that you package up this may be the only way.

Answer (score 1):

This warning is specific to NuGet. When manually adding a dll, no part in the build checks the target framework of that dll (in theory, most dll files should carry a `TargetFrameworkAttribute` assembly metadata but it isn't required) and you are responsible for making sure that you are using a compatible assembly.

To silence this NuGet warning (and accepting that there may be issues at run-time when using a package originally authored for .NET Framework), you can add this `NoWarn` metadata to your package reference:

```
<PackageReference Include="My.Package" Version="1.2.3" NoWarn="NU1603" />
```